# How to block or detect AdBlock using jQuery (No GitHub needed)

Tags: search, share, adblock

We are using lukkr.com's adblock detector on our website.
But we need jQuery version.
https://lukkr.com/anti-adblock-script/

```
<!-- Customize / change AdBlock Alert here -->
<script>var abpalertmsg="AdBlock is enabled. \nPlease keep supporting us by disabling your ad blocker. \n\nThank You!";</script>

<script>!function(){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript",e.async=true,e.src="//lukkr.com/website/noadblock.js";var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(e,t)}();</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript framework, you can just use the code as it is.

Comment: How does the code above work? Can it disable adblocker?